# Unable to send the value of two attributes to JSP from servlet using requestdispatcher

Tags: servlets, requestdispatcher

Please help . Below is my code to redirect the request with two attributes to JSP but both of the below two attributes returns the value of passWord .
1)user_Name

2)Pass_word

for example , ABC is my username and XYZ is my password which is get from the "FORM" but my second value i.e the value of the passWord variable is appears in both of the attribute.

**printing inside the jsp page :**

user_Name: XYS   (Should be ABC instead of XYZ)

pass_Word: XYZ

**servlet :**

```
import java.io.IOException;    
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.Servlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class JndiConn extends HttpServlet implements Servlet {

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 throws ServletException, IOException {

 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
 String userName=request.getParameter("Username");
 String passWord=request.getParameter("password");
 String user_Name="";
 request.setAttribute(user_Name,userName);
 String pass_Word="";
 request.setAttribute(pass_Word,passWord);
RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher ("GetParameter.jsp"); 
System.out.println(userName);
System.out.println(passWord);
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

Connection connection = getConnection();
 if (connection != null) {
  String sql = "SELECT count(1) FROM scott.login_user where login_id ='"+userName+"' and password='"+passWord+"'";
  String sql1 = "select SYSDATE from dual";
  System.out.println(sql);
  try{
  PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
  ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();

  while (rs.next()) {
         int number=rs.getInt("count(1)");
     System.out.println("Result value is "+number);
     if(number==1)
     {
    System.out.println("THE LOGIN SUCCESS FOR::"+userName);
    String sql2 = "INSERT INTO SCOTT.LOGIN_USER VALUES(3,'VINOTH','vinoth55','SCOTT',to_date('08/06/13','DD/MM/RR'),105)";
    PreparedStatement statement1 = connection.prepareStatement(sql2);
    ResultSet rs1 = statement1.executeQuery();
   rd.forward(request, response);
  } 
     else{

         System.out.println("THE LOGIN FAILURE FOR "+userName);
         rd.forward(request, response); 
             }
 }

 connection.close();
 }catch(Exception e){
   System.out.println(e);
 }
 }


}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, IOException {
}

private Connection getConnection() {
 Connection connection = null;
 try {
 InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
 DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) context.lookup("vinothprd");

 connection = dataSource.getConnection();
 } catch (NamingException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (SQLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
 return connection;
 } 
}
```

Below is my JSP to print the user_Name and pass_Word :

**JSP:**

```
String user_Name="";
String userName=(String)request.getAttribute(user_Name);
String pass_Word="";
String passWord=(String)request.getAttribute(pass_Word);
System.out.println("user_Name: "+userName);
System.out.println("pass_Word: "+passWord);
```

Thanks for your help in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Servlet` you are setting, attributes using empty value.

```
 String user_Name="";
 request.setAttribute(user_Name,userName);
 String pass_Word="";
 request.setAttribute(pass_Word,passWord);
```

First of all, this is wrong and I don't know why you are doing this.

In JSP, When you access `request.getAttribute(user_Name); // which is empty ""`,
you will get the value of password as username was overridden.

Solution:

You should set attribute like

EDIT Servlet

```
 String userName=request.getParameter("Username");
 String passWord=request.getParameter("password");

 String user_Name="userName";
 request.setAttribute(user_Name, userName);
 String pass_Word="passWord";
 request.setAttribute(pass_Word, passWord);
```

then in JSP

```
String user_Name="userName"
String userName=(String) request.getAttribute(user_Name);

String pass_Word="passWord";
String passWord=(String)request.getAttribute(pass_Word);
```

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute

Comment: Hi Hardik Mishra, thanks a lot it's working now.
But would like to understand
1)How I'm able to get the value of the password in JSP although I'm initiating pass_Word variable as same as user_Name.
2)Why still empty value assign to user_Name although pass the value of userName to user_Name in the request.setAttribute

Comment: First argument in the `setAttribute()` is the value and second one is the object which you want to pass

Comment: My code is as follows in source file:-
`request.setAttribute("abcd","done");
    if(request.getRequestURL().indexOf("something")<0)
        request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request,response);`

Code in the destination file:- `System.out.println("request.getAttribute(abcd)============================"+request.getAttribute("abcd"));`
It always prints NULL. I've tried response.redirect and jsp forward as well, but not able to read the param/attribute in the destination file